# Copy RLMObject ,Modify and then save

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So what im trying to do is, retrieve the object that is already saved on Realm, modify some properties and then save it again, keeping only one record on the database.

Heres my code :

Getting the Realm already saved user

```
if let user = User.query() {
   user.latitude = String(latitude)
   user.longitude = String(longitude)
   user.save()
}
```

User query func, inside User Obj

```
static func query() -> User? {
    return User.allObjects().toArray(User.self).first
}

func save() -> User {
    RealmPersister.saveObjects([self])
    return self
}
```

And the RealmPersister class func

```
class func saveObjects(objects: [RLMObject]?) {
    autoreleasepool {
        guard let objects = objects where objects.count > 0 else { return }
        do {
            let realm = RealmEncrypted.realm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.addObjects(objects)
            try realm.commitWriteTransaction()}
        catch {
            print("Realm did not write objects! \(objects)")
        }
    }
}

class func deleteObjects(objects: [RLMObject]?) {
    autoreleasepool {
        guard let objects = objects where objects.count > 0 else { return }
        do {
            let realm = RealmEncrypted.realm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.deleteObjects(objects)
            try realm.commitWriteTransaction()
        } catch {
            print("Realm did not delete objects! \(objects)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears that you need to be using primary keys on the `User` object. This way you can retrieve the same object quickly via the primary key, modify it, and then save it without the possibility of creating duplicates.